# Table view reuseable self-sizing cells with changing sub-views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableView`

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0f;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MyTableViewCell class])];
```

And a custom `UITableViewCell` with a custom view:

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell {

}

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setupView {
    self.wrapperView = [UIView new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.wrapperView];

    self.firstView = [UIView new];
    self.secondView = [UIView new];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.wrapperView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
    [self.wrapperView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.contentView);
    }];

    UIView *previous;
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.wrapperView.subviews.count; index++) {
        UIView *subview = self.wrapperView.subviews[index];
        [subview mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            if (!previous) {
                make.top.equalTo(self.wrapperView);
            }
            else {
                make.top.equalTo(previous.mas_bottom);
            }

            make.left.equalTo(self.wrapperView);
            make.right.equalTo(self.wrapperView);
            make.height.equalTo(@50.0f);

            if (index == self.wrapperView.subviews.count - 1) {
                make.bottom.equalTo(self.wrapperView);
            }
        }];

        previous = subview;
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void)populate:(NSInteger)index {
    [self.wrapperView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    [self.wrapperView addSubview:self.firstView];
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        [self.wrapperView addSubview:self.secondView];
    }

    [self updateConstraints];
}

@end
```

The `UITableViewDelegate` is implemented as such:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MyTableViewCell class])];
    [cell populate:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see i alternate between showing the `secondView` and when alternating im changing the constraints (using masonry) to bind the `wrapperView` edges to its subviews (to allow for self-sizing)

The problem is it seems `UITableView` cant figure out the height when reusing cells. This causes the following two errors to occur when scrolling down the cells:

**Error 1**: (Here its complaining theres too much "height" (50px) because we are reusing a cell which used to display `secondView`)

```
2015-10-19 09:52:54.075 SelfsizingTest[32296:1615907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c3adaf40 UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9750.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5c3ad8f30.top>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c3adb1c0 UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9750.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5c3ad8f30.bottom>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c1543da0 UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9980.top == UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9750.top>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c15453c0 UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9980.bottom == UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9750.bottom>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c3c0d5d0 UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9980.height == 50>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c3ae2440 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5c3ad8f30.height == 100>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fc5c3c0d5d0 UIView:0x7fc5c3ad9980.height == 50>
```

**Error 2**: (Here its complaining about that theres not enough "height" to allow for `secondView` to be displayed (missing 50pixels)) happens when reusing a cell which previously did not display `secondView`

```
2015-10-19 10:02:49.667 SelfsizingTest[32565:1625337] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628420250 UIView:0x7f962841eb40.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f962841b1e0.top>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f96284204d0 UIView:0x7f962841eb40.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f962841b1e0.bottom>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628421560 UIView:0x7f962841ed70.height == 50>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628628a70 UIView:0x7f962841ed70.top == UIView:0x7f962841eb40.top>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f96286293e0 UIView:0x7f962841eef0.top == UIView:0x7f962841ed70.bottom>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628629d80 UIView:0x7f962841eef0.height == 50>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628629f00 UIView:0x7f962841eef0.bottom == UIView:0x7f962841eb40.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628422490 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f962841b1e0.height == 50>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f9628629d80 UIView:0x7f962841eef0.height == 50>
```

So my question is how do i use self-sizing cells when cells which can change its subview structure during "population" of the cells.

I guess one way to solve this would be to have a separate cell for each combination but in my "real" case this would result in alot of cells.

Ive uploaded an example project where i reproduce the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyyzvxpkud7bcta/SelfsizingTest.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your height in layout subviews and assign  them in a  instance variable . The calculation will be based on the data required and the subviews involved.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    .....
    self.heightEstimated = <some_variable_you_calulate_required_height_based_onSubview>;
}
```

then create a dummy cell variable which is used only for calculating height

`static MyCell *_mannequinCell;`

now create a dummy cell only once

```
+ (MyCell *)mannequinCell {
    if (!_mannequinCell) {
        _mannequinCell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
    }
    return _mannequinCell;
}
```

Now whenever you need to find size based on the data, which can be varied due to data/subviews. Just create a method like the one below.

```
+ (CGFloat)heightRequiredWithData:(Model *)data {
    [[MyCell mannequinCell] populateCellWithData:data];
    [[MyCell mannequinCell] layoutSubviews];
    return [MyCell mannequinCell].heightEstimated;
}
```

Comment: This approach is much like what is used to do before UITableView self-sizing support, it would be great if i could continue using self-sizing cells instead of calculating the height of the cells manually.